# copy specific lines from one file to next

Tags: cmd

question-1) i have two files

file1 has

```
abc=123
acd=234
helloa=455
hellob=768
adb=234
```

file2 has

```
abc=123
acd=564
helloa=2343
hellob=123
adb=685
```

i know the string `helloa` and `hellob` but i dont know whats on the right side of it,
what i want to do is,change the values on right side in `helloa` and `hellob` of file1 to those of file2.

what i have tried

```
set a=0
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('^<file1 findstr /n "^"') do (
set "line=%%i"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "line=!line:*:=!"
if not "!line!"=="!line:helloa=!" set a=!line!
endlocal
)
```

and then replacing the lines in file1 but the lines never get copied to a, a is still 0

question-2) an extension of this
the file1 has

```
line1
line2
hello1
hello2
```

file2

```
line1
line2
hello1
hello2
hello3
```

here i want to delete all `hello` lines in file1 and replace them with `hello` lines of file2

Comment: Re Q2:  Do you want all hello lines removed from file1 and have all the hello lines from file 2 added to the end of file1

Comment: `question-2)` makes no sense for me, replace `hello1` with `hello1` ?  You can add `hello3`  and ready.

Comment: I gather that the OP wasn't being clear when typing the examples, and that file2 has different lines with `hello` in them.

Comment: alright example  `file1` - `hello1` 'hello2` and `file2` `hello3` `hello4` and hello5 now i want to replace all hello lines of file1 with those of file2. (not equal no.) it must be replaced in the position the hello lines of file1 were

Comment: This can only be solved, if all hello lines in file1 stay together **or** more information about the distribution of the hello lines. Nevertheless, you should make a new question for Q2.

Comment: all hello lines in both file1 and file2 are together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves Q1

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ('find "helloa" ^< file2.txt') do set helloa=%%b
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ('find "hellob" ^< file2.txt') do set hellob=%%b

for /f "delims=" %%a in (file1.txt) do (
for /f "delims==" %%b in ("%%a") do (
if "%%b"=="helloa" (
>>file.tmp echo helloa=%helloa%
) else if "%%b"=="hellob" (
>>file.tmp echo hellob=%hellob%
) else (
>>file.tmp echo(%%a
)
)
)
move file.tmp file1.txt
pause
```